# Design: Selling content on 3rd party site

Tags: design-patterns

Just need some advice as I'm new to this territory and not sure what the best approach is.

I have a site where we sell online courses like udemy or appsumo or lynda. People pay on the site and can access/stream videos and quizzes online.

Now I'm partnering with a 3rd party site which will sell our courses but we are custom making courses for this site and these courses will not be available on my site for my users. Similarly the courses available on my site should not visible to users who come from this 3rd party site.

The idea is - on the 3rd party site - the user is going to view the course details, register and pay online after which the user will be redirected to my site. The user should not get any indication that he has come to my site - the look and feel should be similar to the 3rd party site and the URL will be masked as well. It goes without saying that while he is on my site - he should not be able to access any of my current pages like "view courses", "about us" "contact us" etc etc

Basically the idea is the user will never know about my site. Even next time when he wants to access the course - he will login on the 3rd party site and get redirected here.

So the tech team on the other end is suggesting that I should make a new build with just the main course pages and a new layout and deploy it on a separate server but pointing to the same back end database.

The idea of maintaining two versions of the same site doesn't seem right to me.

Need some advice from experts who've been there and done that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be that you should make an API for them to access the content instead of redirecting. This way you are only responsible for serving the content, and the integration is totally on them. Furthermore, if similar partnerships with other parties arise in the future you are already set up for that.

Comment: Thanks prod - I did think about that approach but its going to take a while for me to develop the API. And more over - they are basically a content portal and dont want the headache of integrating with us. Initially it was just videos and I suggested I would provide them with the embed link for which itself they did not agree but not we have the whole adaptive quizzes built for each video - so that is definitely something they will not agree. But for future partnerships - I agree API is the way to go